# sending spark dataframe via email without using pandas in pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to send spark dataframe via email.
normally i'm able to send spark dataframe by converting spark dataframe to pandas and using to_html() function to send spark dataframe as email..

as i don't have pandas package in server .can anyone tell is there any other alternate to send spark dataframe via email without using pandas

i followed below code
[image]

I'm automating the whole process. can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to send dataframe via email. But to answer your question, maybe you should write it down as csv then attach to the email?